# Monodroid - Loading a custom activity

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android

I'm currently trying to develop an application under Android using Mono.
I'd like to add support for plugins to my application so additional features could be brought to it.

I was able to load simple .dll at runtime in my program, however whenever I try creating a dll implementing both my interface and a custom activity, an exception of type Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError is thrown.

There is the class inside the dll code:

```
[Activity (Label = "Vestiaire")]
public class Vestiaire : Activity, IModule
{   

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }

    void OnClickVestiaireButton(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ;
    }

    public void InitVestiaireModule()
    {
        Run();
    }

    public Type LaunchActivity ()
    {
        return typeof(Vestiaire);
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        Name = "Vestiaire Module";
        Version = "0.1";
    }

    public void Run()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
    }
}
```

The line responsible for the exception: (from the program core)

```
LoadedPlugin.Add((IModule)(Activator.CreateInstance(Plugin)));
```

Things I'm actually wonderring are:
- Is it possible to actually achieve what i'm trying to ?
If yes, help would be apreciated on that problem :P

Otherwise what would be the best alternative ?
Global point is to be able to load a custom menu at runtime loaded from a dll.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the key to your problem is that the Activity needs to be registered in you Manifest.xml file.

For Activities in you main app, MonoDroid does this for you - but I don't think this will work for your plugin.

Things you could try are:

- putting the Activity in the Manifest yourself (MonoDroid does seem very capable at merging these files)
- if that doesn't work, then you could try using a Fragment instead - and loading the Fragment into a custom FragmentActivity in your main app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and sorry for not getting back to you earlier.
Do you have any link treating about that subject ?